# Mac Version of Wine 8.0.1 Stable. Using Apple Silicon with Rosetta2. Winetricks fails to run "Bad CPU type in executable" Also tells to upgrade to 7.x

Tags: mac, wine, winetricks

Installed Wine using Homebrew and downloaded Winetricks using wget. I ran `chmod +x winetricks` and started it up and got greeted with 2 errors with one pop-up error. And that was the "Bad CPU type in executable" error. Also, in the terminal, I saw another error that came before the pop-up one telling me that I should upgrade to 7.x meanwhile I have 8.0.1. I have Rosetta2 installed. My Wine is working fine, it got compatibility on its mind. I tried to install winetricks and that also didn't work.

Comment: *"Bad CPU type in executable"* is doublespeak for 'you're trying to run Intel code on ARM'. It's never more helpful than that, but it does mean something is not going through Rosetta. [No idea how to fix, sorry.]